# How to interface Pyomo with GLPK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glpk, pyomo

```
opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
opt.options["mipgap"] = 0.05
opt.options["FeasibilityTol"] = 1e-05
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory("serial")
# results = solver_manager.solve(instance, opt=opt, tee=True,timelimit=None, mipgap=0.1)

results = solver_manager.solve(model, opt=opt, tee=True, timelimit=None)

# sends results to stdout
# results.write()

def pyomo_save_results(options=None, instance=None, results=None):
    OUTPUT = open(r'Results_generic_hub.txt', 'w')
    print(results, file=OUTPUT)
    OUTPUT.close()
```

---

It generates the following error. GLPK is installed with GLPSOL -- help working from any directory. Is this a problem with the GLPK module? Or with the model itself? Environment: - Conda, Mac OS Yosemite.

---

```
File "<ipython-input-7-ba156f9322b2>", line 7, in <module>
results = solver_manager.solve(model, opt=opt, tee=True,timelimit=None)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/async_solver.py", line 34, in solve
return self.execute(*args, **kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/manager.py", line 107, in execute
ah = self.queue(*args, **kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/manager.py", line 122, in queue
return self._perform_queue(ah, *args, **kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/local.py", line 59, in _perform_queue
results = opt.solve(*args, **kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 582, in solve
self._presolve(*args, **kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/solver/shellcmd.py", line 196, in _presolve
OptSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 661, in _presolve
**kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 729, in _convert_problem
**kwds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/convert.py", line 110, in convert_problem
problem_files, symbol_map = converter.apply(*tmp, **tmpkw)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/solvers/plugins/converter/model.py", line 86, in apply
io_options=io_options)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py", line 1646, in write
io_options)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/repn/plugins/cpxlp.py", line 163, in __call__
include_all_variable_bounds=include_all_variable_bounds)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/repn/plugins/cpxlp.py", line 575, in _print_model_LP
" cannot write legal LP file" % str(model.name))

ValueError: ERROR: No objectives defined for input model 'unknown';  cannot write legal LP file
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing:

```
"ERROR: No objectives defined for input model 'unknown';  cannot write legal LP file"
```

indicates that Pyomo cannot find an active Objective component on your model (either you never added one to the model, or the Objective component(s) were all deactivated).  Either way, valid LP files (which is how Pyomo interfaces with GLPK) require an objective.  Fixing your model by adding an Objective should resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the end of the script:

```
> instance  = model.create() instance.pprint() opt =
> SolverFactory("glpk") results = opt.solve(instance)
> print(results)
```

`